# Responsiveness of a webpage In all devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created the following page here I added one background image,This page is not responsive in all devices.
What I did wrong?I used bootstrap.I want that image also should be responsive in all devices.I don't want full image should be displayed in mobile view.But when I see in mobile view it should be good to see.
please help me.

```
<div class="container">
   <section class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="alert alert-danger col-lg-4 invalidData">
            <span class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</span>
            <strong id="errorMessage">Missing required field!</strong>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-xs-12 formBorder padding">
        <header class="loginHeader">Login To Go</header>
        <form method="post" action="" name="login" id="login" class="paddingTopBottom">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 fieldPadding">
                <input type="text" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter email here">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 fieldPadding">
                <input type="password" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12" name="pwd" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password here">
            </div>
        </form>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 fieldPadding">
                <input type="submit" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 btn btn-info" name="submit" id="submit" value="Go With Credentials" onclick="checkDetails()">
            </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pszex85n/

Comment: Have a look at this https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: @user7397787 if you use "background-attachment: fixed" in your css, background will not be responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I din't add this line in my header that is why I got some errors

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

And I got good background for mobile view By change the following css

```
background-position: 53% 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix your css:

```
.img {
    backgroud: url('your background image url') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

and after that use media query to fix your size on different devices